# Howto compare two entities in JPA onPreUpdate

Tags: java, jpa, persistence

I am working with OpenJPA 2.2.1 and would like to do the following:

1) Load an entity
2) Change the entity
3) Check the changes done before saving the entity

What I've done:

1) Load the entity via

```
    EntityManager.find(MyObject.class, id);
```

2) Ok, pretty clear, I think, something like

```
    MyObject obj = EntityManager.find(MyObject.class, id);
    obj.setName("New name");
```

3) Tried to evict the object from the PersistenceContext and loading it again from the database via:

```
    EntityManager.evict(MyObject.class, id);
    EntityManager.find(MyObject.class, id);
```

The entity returned by the find() call in 3) is always equal (equal ID) to the entity found in 1)

I thought I could remove the entity from the PersistenceContext / cache by evict.

How can I achieve to have two different entities:
a) the changed entity and 
b) the original entity from the database loaded in step 3)

And: If i refresh() the entity I expect the find method to return the refreshed one. Is that correct?

I tried the @PreUpdate listeners too with the same result so I think there must be something I have not understood regarding JPA PersistenceContext or Java references...

I hope I provided enough information! Thanks in advance!

Comment: With "equal ID" you mean that both `MyObject` instances have the same `id` value? Because that's exactly what you asked the entityManager for...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a good overview of the JPA lifecycle I found this site (particularly the state diagram) to be helpful: http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/managed

The main take-away is that objects don't "disappear" when you remove them from the persistence context. Your `obj` will still point to a fully initialized `MyObject` with `name` set to "New name". The only difference is that committing the transaction/flushing the persistence context will no longer update the corresponding database entry.

You have several options when you want to look at the changes to `obj` before committing to the database. If quick and dirty suffices, I'd suggest

```
MyObject original = obj.clone();
```

and compare `obj` and `original` with whatever tool (or just plain printing both to your log) you like.

Regarding `refresh()`, have a look at what [this page](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/retrieve#Retrieval_by_Refresh_) says:

> The content of the managed object in memory is discarded (including changes, if any) and replaced by data that is retrieved from the database. This might be useful to ensure that the application deals with the most up to date version of an entity object, just in case it might have been changed by another EntityManager since it was retrieved.

Comment: Hi, mabi, many thanks for your explanations. Just that I understand right:

Comment: managed -> changes are comitted, removed -> entity will be deleted on commit, detached -> nothing happens when comitting. Seems,Cache.evict() only works with L2 Cache which I do not use, so I tried detaching it which did not work either. I saw here [link](http://tomee.apache.org/jpa-concepts.html) that the detaching means to remove the entity from the PersistenceContext, so I wonder why find() gives me the original reference and does not reload the entity from the database?

Comment: Yes, you are correct about managed, removed and detached. Have you verified it's the same *reference*, as in "the very same object instance"? If yes, try starting a new session. I've no experience with OpenJPA but Hibernate also has a per-session cache to fetch entities from. Anyway, if you clone/copy-construct a copy of your entity, you can just continue without detaching and compare the two whenever you like.

Comment: Allright. I will do the cloning. There are no sessions in OpenJPA. Regarding the reference: yes, it is the same object with the same ID. Thanks again for your help. Cannot vote your answer up, got no reputation ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you use Spring @Transactional like me. You can do the following:

```
@Transactional
MyEntityObject update(MyEntityObject myEntityObject){
   boolean isNameChanged;
   em.detach(myEntityObject);
   MyEntityObject inDBObject = em.load(myEntityObject.getId());
   isNameChanged = (myEntityObject.getName() != inDBObject.getName());
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How did you init `em`? Will you still be able to save `myEntityObject`?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

1/ Read (or find) the object into memory [which is what you have done]

2/ Remove the object from the store; something along the lines of:

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.remove(obj);
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

3/ Do whatever updates on the object in memory;

```
obj.setName("My New Name");
```

4/ Finally persist the updated object:

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.persist(obj);
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

The above snippets are based on the `javax.persistence.*;` package and `em` is an instance defined like so:

```
EntityManagerFactory emFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENT_UNIT);
EntityManager em = emFactory.createEntityManager();
```

All the best!

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I was looking for a way to compare the original and changed entity. With your way I delete the original and persist the changed one again so I cannot compare.